# Image disappears when given position:absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of images in a div that is relatively positioned. In order to stack the images on top of each other I'm trying to absolutely position them.

However once I apply `position: absolute` to the image, it disappears. I'm using jcarouselite for the carousel so I'm not sure if something in the jcarousel script could be causing this.

```css
#sliderContainer {
  position: relative;
}
#sliderBtnPrev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
#sliderBtnPrev img {
  margin: 0px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#sliderBtnNext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  right: 50px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
#sliderBtnNext img {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.slideImg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
}
.slideTxt {
  float: left;
  margin: -278px 0px 0px 150px;
  background: rgba(20, 0, 17, .5);
  width: 380px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  z-index: 100;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sliderContainer">
  <div id="sliderBtnPrev">
    <img src='http://www.placehold.it/200' alt="Previous">
  </div>
  <!-- end of sliderBtnPrev -->
  <div id="sliderBtnNext">
    <img src='http://www.placehold.it/200' alt="Next">
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" alt="Slide" class="slideImg">
      <p class="slideTxt">For every service rendered, for every man hour utilized, we make it count for you through quality training delivery service.
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" alt="Slide" class="slideImg">
      <p class="slideTxt">Lorem ipsum id aptent suscipit curae donec nunc dolor,consectetur congue dolor viverra euismod.
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" alt="Slide" class="slideImg">
      <p class="slideTxt">Lorem ipsum id aptent suscipit curae donec nunc dolor,consectetur congue dolor viverra euismod.
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- end of sliderContainer -->

Jcarouselite code

    // JavaScript Document
(function($){$.fn.jCarouselLite=function(o){o=$.extend({btnPrev:null,btnNext:null,btnGo:null,mouseWheel:false,auto:null,speed:200,easing:null,vertical:false,circular:true,visible:3,start:0,scroll:1,beforeStart:null,afterEnd:null},o||{});
 return this.each(function(){var b=false,animCss=o.vertical?"top":"left",sizeCss=o.vertical?"height":"width";
 var c=$(this),ul=$("ul",c),tLi=$("li",ul),tl=tLi.size(),v=o.visible;if(o.circular){ul.prepend(tLi.slice(tl-v-1+1).clone()).append(tLi.slice(0,v).clone());
  o.start+=v}var f=$("li",ul),itemLength=f.size(),curr=o.start;c.css("visibility","visible");f.css({overflow:"hidden",float:o.vertical?"none":"left"});
  ul.css({margin:"0",padding:"0",position:"relative","list-style-type":"none","z-index":"1"});c.css({overflow:"hidden",position:"relative","z-index":"2",left:"0px"});
  var g=o.vertical?height(f):width(f);var h=g*itemLength;var j=g*v;f.css({width:f.width(),height:f.height()});ul.css(sizeCss,h+"px").css(animCss,-(curr*g));
  c.css(sizeCss,j+"px");if(o.btnPrev)$(o.btnPrev).click(function(){return go(curr-o.scroll)});if(o.btnNext)$(o.btnNext).click(function(){return go(curr+o.scroll)});
  if(o.btnGo)$.each(o.btnGo,function(i,a){$(a).click(function(){return go(o.circular?o.visible+i:i)})});if(o.mouseWheel&&c.mousewheel)c.mousewheel(function(e,d){return d>0?go(curr-o.scroll):go(curr+o.scroll)});
  if(o.auto)setInterval(function(){go(curr+o.scroll)},o.auto+o.speed);function vis(){return f.slice(curr).slice(0,v)};function go(a){if(!b){if(o.beforeStart)o.beforeStart.call(this,vis());if(o.circular){if(a<=o.start-v-1){ul.css(animCss,-((itemLength-(v*2))*g)+"px");curr=a==o.start-v-1?itemLength-(v*2)-1:itemLength-(v*2)-o.scroll}else if(a>=itemLength-v+1){ul.css(animCss,-((v)*g)+"px");curr=a==itemLength-v+1?v+1:v+o.scroll}else curr=a}else{if(a<0||a>itemLength-v)return;
   else curr=a}b=true;ul.animate(animCss=="left"?{left:-(curr*g)}:{top:-(curr*g)},o.speed,o.easing,function(){if(o.afterEnd)o.afterEnd.call(this,vis());b=false});if(!o.circular){$(o.btnPrev+","+o.btnNext).removeClass("disabled");$((curr-o.scroll<0&&o.btnPrev)||(curr+o.scroll>itemLength-v&&o.btnNext)||[]).addClass("disabled")}}return false}})};function css(a,b){return parseInt($.css(a[0],b))||0};function width(a){return a[0].offsetWidth+css(a,'marginLeft')+css(a,'marginRight')};function height(a){return a[0].offsetHeight+css(a,'marginTop')+css(a,'marginBottom')}})(jQuery);

what i have in my functions.js

// JavaScript Document
$(window).load(function(){
   //Activate the Slider
   $("#sliderContainer").jCarouselLite({
    btnNext: "#sliderBtnNext",
    btnPrev: "#sliderBtnPrev",
    visible:1,
    circular:true,
    scroll:1
 });
 });
```

Comment: @Umi Images appear present though "stacked" on top of each other with `css` `position:absolute` . Try setting `ul li {position:abosolute}` as well. Can include "jcarousel" `js` at Question ?

Comment: it does show when i use `ul li {position:absolute}` if i'm offline so the jcarouselite is not working. The images disappear when i go online. I think it might have to do with the script but i can't figure it out.

Comment: @Umi Yes. Appear to be plugin. Before included `js` tried with http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/basic/ ; images displayed appeared ok.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sg1fy4df/

Answer (score 0):

You've defined your first image as both position: relative and position: absolute. Could that be causing the error?

Your code:

```
#sliderContainer {
  position: relative;
}
#sliderBtnPrev {
  position: absolute;


<div id="sliderContainer">
  <div id="sliderBtnPrev">
    <img src='http://www.placehold.it/200' alt="Previous">
  </div>
```

Comment: no i was referring to the images in the list. `#sliderBtnPrev` is for the previous buttons which are positioned ok. my problem has to do with the images in the list. seems to be coming from the javascript code.